# How to make bootstrap btn-group break into half naturally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been avoiding finding a real solution to this problem, and often just sacrifice what I initially was aiming for to get around it.

I enjoy using the Bootstrap .btn-group class. It has a lot of nice uses. Unfortunately, it makes centering and responsiveness a pain. Say I built this.

```
<div id="nav-bar" class="btn-group" role="group">
  <a class="nav-btn btn btn-default" >example 1</a>
  <a class="nav-btn btn btn-default" >example 2</a>
  <a class="nav-btn btn btn-default" >example 3</a>
  <a class="nav-btn btn btn-default" >example 4</a>
</div>
```

When the screen gets small, the entire bar might not fit, in which case I would want two nav bars, top one with the first two btns, and the bottom one with the last two btns. Instead what happens is it shows 3 btns on top, and 1 on the bottom until the screen is small enough to force it to be 2 by 2 like I want.

On what is likely a related note, I cannot center btn-groups without specifying a left margin either, making btns with variable width practically impossible.. I've tried every combination of text-align: center, and margin: 0 auto that I could, as well as adding and applying various parents, div and span, and apply those properties as well. I can't use the bootstrap grid property, because it breaks the functionality of the .btn-group class.

It would seem the semantics of the HTML is making what I want impossible, at least without giving certain screen sizes certain HTML documents, but I've always known CSS to be able to solve anything visual. How can I have my navbar respond appropriately to screen size?

Comment: Did you try wrapping your nav buttons in div class="row" and div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bootstrap resizing system uses row containers classes filled with the "12 sum" rule. using classes

> col-xs-**x**; col-xm-**x**; col-md-**x**; col-lg-**x**

where x is is an integer 1 <= x <= 12

this integer determines the width of a column within the row, as a part of the whole - 12 parts total. The middle characters indicate the size at which the row will convert to a column (from 1x4 to 4x1), i.e. resizes itself for a narrower display. The screen sizes for each are given here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

I suggest you use this row/column system to create a table that moves from 1x4 to 2x2 once the desired screen size is reached. Here's a skeletal frame:

```
<div class='row'>                  1x4
    <div class='col-md-6'>              2x2
        anchor1
        anchor2
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        anchor3
        anchor4
    </div>
</div>
```

This would make a button group that starts out as a 1x4 then once the medium screen size is reached converts to a 2x2, medium just an arbitrary choice

Answer (score 1):

Make media queries

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    .nav-btn{
        width:50%;
        }
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9481/